# tikz rectangle that fits exacly into linewidth including boundary

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I had this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}    
\newcommand{\mywidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (\mywidth,2); %this line produces the overfull \hbox
\node[draw,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=1cm] at (\mywidth-4cm/2,1cm/2) {right lower corner};
\node[draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm] at (\mywidth/2,1cm/2) {middle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gave me an `overfull \hbox (1.6pt too wide)`

so I wanted to change `\newcommand{\mywidth}{\linewidth-1.6pt}` but then the parenthesis in the calculations don't work.

So I changed every `\mywidth/2` by `{(\mywidth/2)}` where `{ }` alwayshas to surround the whole expression.

My actual `tikzpicture` is much more complicated containing many formulas that build on `\mywidth` and it is lots of work to change all of them.

Is there a more elegant way to get rid of this `overfull \hbox` without destroying all the alignments within the graphic?

Can I somehow put parenthesis inside `\newcommand{\mywidth}{\linewidth-1.6pt}`?

Bonus question. What happens when I change `ultra thick` to `very thick`? This gives me a very uggly number in the `overfull \hbox` warning.

Comment: You need to subtract half the line width from each ends: `\draw[ultra thick] (\pgflinewidth/2,0) rectangle (\mywidth-\pgflinewidth/2,2);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My proposal is:

1. replace your `rectangle` by a node;
2. create a style that specify the "exterior size" of the nodes;
3. use anchors to position your nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  exterior size/.style args={#1x#2}{
    outer sep=auto,
    minimum width={#1-\pgflinewidth},
    minimum height={#2-\pgflinewidth}
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=draw]
      \path[ultra thick] (0,0) node[exterior size=\linewidth x 2cm, anchor=south west](R){};
      \node[red, line width=1.5mm, exterior size=4cm x 1cm, anchor=south east] at (R.south east) {right lower corner};
      \node[green, exterior size=4cm x 1cm, anchor=south] at (R.south) {middle};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I give my welcome for your long absence. on TeX.SE.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks, but probably it will be a short stay.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subtract half the line width from each ends, and can use anchors for easier positioning without using computations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %<- not used here

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (\pgflinewidth/2,0)  rectangle (\linewidth-\pgflinewidth/2,2); %this line produces the overfull \hbox
\node[draw,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=south east] at (\linewidth,0) {right lower corner};
\node[draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=south] at (\linewidth/2,0) {middle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]